# Populating a Word Template with Excel Data

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, ms-word, mailmerge

So I've been poking around on the interwebs looking for a solution to this for a while now.

I have a Word document that I want to use as a template to welcome new employees into the business.

I also have an Excel file which has the Name, Job Title, Team Name, etc. of all the new employees (each has their own file currently but this can be changed).

The information appears in the document something like this:

Welcome, [NAME]! You are starting with us today as [JOBTITLE], working with the [TEAMNAME] team. You will be working closely alongside [TEAMMEMBERS].

I want to make it so that everywhere on the Word file where it says [NAME] it will say the person's name, [JOBTITLE] becomes their title, etc.

All the labels are repeated in different contexts throughout the document. I'd like to do this with VBA but I can't figure out how, though it feels like it should be simple. I'm not too experienced in, well, anything code-related but I've managed to piece together some VBA successfully in the past so I feel like I have the best chance of managing with that.

I'm using a Mac and really struggling to get my head around the MailMerge feature as it seems to be a much more intuitive system on Windows. Maybe it's the answer, but I can't tell to be honest.

I've had a look at thousands of similar posts and can't seem to find my answer, can anybody help please?

Comment: I suggest you ask in an end-user venue, such as Super User, how to use Mail Merge on the Mac. As far as a VBA solution goes, there are also massive problems trying to run one Office application from within another on the Mac. Even if that were not the case, Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service or a tutorial site. This question is "too broad" - you're professionals - who get paid for coding - to write the entire code for you. Please review the site's usage guidelines in the [help] to better understand what Stack Overflow is for and how to ask here.

Comment: Alternatively, use the record macro feature in Word to record yourself replacing the word [NAME} with a specific name, and then use that code as a basis to produce a series of replace statements for each option (NAME, JobTitle etc). Then you just have to find code to read a cell in excel from within word, which is what google is for...:-)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.

Set a 'Reference' to Word under Tools > References, then run the code below (runs from Excel).

```
Sub PushToWord()

Dim objWord As New Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim bkmk As Word.Bookmark
sWdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , , , False)
Set doc = objWord.Documents.Open(sWdFileName)
'On Error Resume Next

objWord.ActiveDocument.variables("BrokerFirstName").Value = Range("BrokerFirstName").Value
objWord.ActiveDocument.variables("BrokerLastName").Value = Range("BrokerLastName").Value
objWord.ActiveDocument.variables("Ryan").Value = Range("Ryan").Value


objWord.ActiveDocument.Fields.Update

'On Error Resume Next
objWord.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Remember to add `DocVariables` to your Word file.  You can do the same with Bookmarks.